# Changing button name MFC Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, mfc

I just started the GUI development, i had started on C++Builder but i switched to Visual Studio for differents reasons. But in Visual Studio, i've got a big problem :

In the GUI development interface (rc file) i can create buttons and place it, but i can't change there names. The name for all of MFC components i placed is initialize to a default name which i can't call and i can't change the property by the properties interface, i can change the Text, for change the Label of the Button, but not the name...
It's very incomfortable because by that i can't call my buttons for do anything, i have the same problem for Listboxs, so i can't modify my list because i can't call there

I just want to modify access my component by my c++ code for modifying this component

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEgTU.png)

Thank for your help !

Comment: A side note: MFC is usually not a good choice these days for developing UI.

Comment: @wohlstad MFC is the *only* supported, native GUI framework there is, even today. It's just not a useful framework for newcomers. That aside, controls do not have names. They have IDs (sometimes), and those IDs can be defined using symbolic constants (usually in a *Resource.h* file, that's used by both C++ code and the .rc script). To learn those fundamental concepts it's best to not use a framework at all. [This walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows) is a good starting point.

Comment: @IInspectable I wouldn't agrue about native UI frameworks. But I personally prefer (if it's possible) to develop the GUI in winforms (C#) and use C++/CLI to bind to my native code for the engine/logic. BTW I used MFC in the past.

Comment: just adding to the suggestions above: for learning purpose, sticking to a certain framework will save you time and effort. For instance, assuming you wish to stick to C++, for some reason if you abandon MFC now and move onto 'Qt' framework then again you have to start from scratch and adapt/understand Qt frameworks mechanisms and way of working (not to mention all the terminology that comes along with it).

Comment: As for 'calling the button', that is pretty much answered below. I always edit the `ID` field to keep things clear, like `IDC_HELP_MYJUMP`. If you edit it first thing when you create the control, everything should work right. From there, most of the time, right click and add a control, as a control. Don't use `GetDlgItem` like you see in many examples. The only place I've used `GetDlgItem` is when specializing `DDX_Something` global. Now that you have a control you can: `cMyButton.EnableWindow(FALSE);` I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Each control in MFC has its own ID number, we use it to call the control, just like the control name in winform, so you could use the ID of the control to operate on it.

Answer (score 1):

The MFC way of doing event handling is a bit more elaborate.
After the control is created on the form in the designer, an ID is generated ("**IDC_BUTTON1**" in the attached screenshot).
This is the ID that will be used for accessing this UI control from the code.

All this can be done via the designer also as shown in [this article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mfc/mfc_messages_events.htm).

Basically, in the background this generated ID is put in a '**message map**'
([more about message maps here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-maps-mfc?view=msvc-170)).
In short 'message map' is used to specify what action needs to be performed when a certain type of action is done on the UI control by the user.
For, example if the button click is to be handled then in code:
the message map would look like:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CSurface3DView, CView)
  ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, CallMyFunction)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

'ON_BN_CLICKED' is a predefined event macro.

The 'CallMyFunction()' function has to be declared with '**afx_msg**' in the class. Besides please, have a look at [data exchange mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange?view=msvc-170) as well. This know-how about data exchange will come in handy going forward.

Comment: thank's for you help, i'll search around this !

Comment: `afx_msg` expands to nothing. Using it is strictly optional. Besides, control IDs aren't created in the *"background"*. They are very clearly put into a header file. There isn't anything magical going on here, unless MFC is your first exposure to Windows API GUI development.